# dplyr group by string match

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c('jan1', 'jan2', 'jan3', 'jan4', 'feb1', 'feb2', 'mar1', 'mar2', 'mar3'),
             v2 = rnorm(9))
```

I want to summarise the data after grouping them. I want them grouped by the number in `v1`, i.e. one group would be (jan1, feb1, mar1), another one would be (jan2, feb2, mar2) and so on.

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
df %>% group_by(str_detect(v1, '1')) %>% summarise(meanp = mean(v2),
                                 medianp = median(v2))
```

Comment: Can you please provide *representative* sample data. You state that you'd like to group by `v1` but in the sample data you give `v1` takes on only one value. I also don't understand what you want to do with `group_by(str_detect(v1, '1'))`. Why not just `group_by(v1)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = gsub("\\D", "", v1)) %>% 
  summarise(mean_v2 = mean(v2)) # only for illustration
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  grp   mean_v2
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 1      0.0635
#2 2      0.0338
#3 3     -0.130 
#4 4      1.60
```

The `group_by` and `gsub` part creates a grouping variable based on the non-alphabetic characters of variable `v1`, see `?regex`.

**data**

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(v1 = c('jan1', 'jan2', 'jan3', 'jan4', 'feb1', 'feb2', 'mar1', 'mar2', 'mar3'),
                 v2 = rnorm(9))
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `str_remove`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = str_remove(v1, "\\D+")) %>% 
  summarise(mean_v2 = mean(v2))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  grp   mean_v2
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 1      0.0635
#2 2      0.0338
#3 3     -0.130 
#4 4      1.60
```